# Can't name package "documentation"

Tags: go

I guess I missed something in the documentation. Can you please point me to the right doc, or if there is something else, tell me what this is.

Basically, I created a directory called `foo`. Inside `foo` I created another subdirectory `documentation`. In `main.go` I tried to call a function SaySomething` and it failed with `main.go:3:8: build constraints exclude all Go files in /root/foo/documentation`. Then I changed `documentation` to `documentationFoo` and everything worked.

Feels like "documentation" is a reserved word in Go, maybe I'm just missing something obvious here. Please help me find what this is.

```
root@personal:~/foo# go run main.go
main.go:3:8: build constraints exclude all Go files in /root/foo/documentation
root@personal:~/foo# vi main.go
root@personal:~/foo# mv documentation documentationFoo
root@personal:~/foo# vi documentationFoo/documentation.go
root@personal:~/foo# go run main.go
foo
root@personal:~/foo# git diff .
diff --git a/documentation/documentation.go b/documentation/documentation.go
deleted file mode 100644
index 3c325c6..0000000
--- a/documentation/documentation.go
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,7 +0,0 @@
-package documentation
-
-import "fmt"
-
-func SaySomething() {
-       fmt.Println("foo")
-}
diff --git a/main.go b/main.go
index 3e57e59..9b76d75 100644
--- a/main.go
+++ b/main.go
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 package main

-import "./documentation"
+import "./documentationFoo"

 func main() {
-       documentation.SaySomething()
+       documentationFoo.SaySomething()
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package name `documentation` is not reserved by the language, but the build tools exclude files with the package name `documentation`.

Here's the documentation from the [go/build Import function](https://godoc.org/go/build#Context.Import):

> In the directory containing the package, .go, .c, .h, and .s files are considered part of the package except for:
>
> - .go files in package documentation
> - files starting with _ or . (likely editor temporary files)
> - files with build constraints not satisfied by the context

Pick a different package name.